# Is it possible to serve multiple partials from one $routeProvider conditional?

Tags: angularjs

My Angular app has an index.html with simply a `<div ng-view></div>` inside the body. On load, the user is presented with a login screen from a single partial view, served via $routeProvider, and on login success the route changes to the loggedin partial:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',   controller: 'LoginCtrl'}).
    when('/loggedin', {templateUrl: 'partials/loggedin_part.html', controller: 'UserCtrl'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
```

Once logged in however I want three separate partials displayed at the same time: infobar, nav and main (main would be interchangable with whichever nav item was currently being viewed). Currently in my loggedin_part.html I have:

```
<ng-include src="'partials/infobar_part.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'partials/nav_part.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'partials/main_part.html'"></ng-include>
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way to serve up via $routeProvider different sub views? With my current method I would be creating 'holder' partials, such as the loggedin_part.html above for each nav item/route, i.e. (hypothetical):

**loggedin_admin_part.html**

```
<ng-include src="'partials/infobar_part.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'partials/nav_part.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'partials/admin_part.html'"></ng-include>
```

**route**

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',   controller: 'LoginCtrl'}).
    when('/loggedin', {templateUrl: 'partials/loggedin_part.html', controller: 'UserCtrl'}).
    when('/admin', {templateUrl: 'partials/loggedin_admin_part.html', controller: 'AdminCtrl'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
```

and so on for each nav group. Is it possible to skip out the 'holder' partials and just serve multiple partials per route conditional? Something like (note, I'm aware the syntax is wrong, it's the idea I'm trying to illustrate):

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',   controller: 'LoginCtrl'}).
    when('/loggedin', {templateUrl: 'partials/infobar_part.html', 'partials/nav_part.html', 'partials/main_part.html', controller: 'UserCtrl'}).
    when('/admin', {templateUrl: 'partials/infobar_part.html', 'partials/nav_part.html', 'partials/admin_part.html', controller: 'AdminCtrl'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would solve this problem changing what you consider a partial is.

For instance: Don't think about 'login' and 'logedIn' as two different partials. You could use a partial called, for instance, loginStatus_bar. This partial have two (or more) possible states (login, loggedIn, etc...)

In your 'loginStatus_bar' partial you write all the possible bars and you use [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow), [ng-hide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide) for conditionally showing what is necessary.

Something like this (where 'isLoggedIn' is a boolean in the scope):

```
<div ng-show="isLoggedIn" ng-controller="loggedInBar" >
</div>
<div ng-hide="isLoggedIn" ng-controller="loginBar" >
</div>
```

In this way, you don't even need a route, because, probably the 'loginStatus_bar' partial is going to be always visible in your application in one state or other.

Comment: I see what you're saying, however if I don't use the $routeProvider, how can I maintain deep linking throughout the site? Won't this solution make the back and forward buttons redundant, ideally I don't want this to happen?

Comment: Of course, you have to use $routeProvider! But for the main content of your app, not (if you choose this way to work) for the top and navigation bars. I would use three <div> in your main page, one per section (topBar, mainContent, navigationBar) and I would use $routeProvider for changing the mainContent. Sorry if I was not clear enough. After all, if we follow a REST paradigm, the URI should reflect the content of the application, not the state.